# InAppSettingsKit text field notification

Tags: iphone, inappsettingskit

I'm using [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit/) to create a settings screen in my app. I have a `PSTextFieldSpecifier` in my plist, and since it is used for login (username/password), I need to know when the user has finished editing text (i.e. pressed Done button on keyboard, aka `textFieldDidEndEditing` in `UITextFieldDelegate`) in order to try to login (as opposed to having a "Login" button).

Unfortunately there's no method in `IASKSettingsDelegate` for this event, so I'm not sure how to implement this. Am I missing something, or the only solution is to add a new delegate method on my own?

Comment: To downvoter: please explain. Isn't this a legitimate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem:

I ended up using IASKCustomViewSpecifier to create a custom view, as suggested by IASK's author on github. Sounds like the best solution.